# WILDFLY Starting Server through Powershell script

Tags: powershell, server, wildfly-9

We are trying to Start the **WILDFLY** Server using the **powershell** script. Here is the code

```
cmd.exe /c $env:JBOSS_HOME\bin\standalone.bat

write-host "Before Condition Check"

if ($?)
    {
        write-host "WILDFLY Server STARTED....."
    }
    else
    {
        $JBossResult = "FAILED"
        write-host "Error While Starting WILDFLY Server"
    }
```

The server is getting started successfully without any issue, but thing is that it is not coming out of the terminal, hence my next part of the code is not getting executed.

Is there anyway to come out of the terminal without stopping the server, so that I continue to my next step.

Answer (score 1):

Replace this:

```
cmd.exe /c $env:JBOSS_HOME\bin\standalone.bat
```

with this:

```
start-process -filepath "$env:JBOSS_HOME\bin\standalone.bat"
```

Launching cmd.exe directly causes the script to wait for it to exit before continuing.

Comment: It is working locally, but when the same script is being called from another machine using invoke command, the server is not getting started.
Script Name: JBossStart.PS1

Invoke Command
' Invoke-Command -Session $session -command "JBossStart.PS1" '
It is successfully invoking the script, but the server is not getting started. Any idea how to resolve it?

Comment: Are you sure that the `$env:JBOSS_HOME` actually works when called inside a remote session, try replacing it with a hard coded path to test it. you could also wrap your script with a `start-transcript` and `stop-transcript` which will write out what happened to a log file.

Comment: FWIW WildFly 10.1.0.Final does have ps1 scripts included. You can see them here https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly-core/tree/2.2.1.Final/core-feature-pack/src/main/resources/content/bin if you want to have a look.